# ReactJS: Collapsible sidebar overlaying on another component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to add a collapsible sidebar table component which is rendered as an overlay over another component.

The below image is a container of 3 divisions each with a separate component.

```
<Container>
  <ThumbnailContainer/>
  <ImageContainer/>
  <FieldContainer/>
<Container/>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<ThumbnailContainer/>        <ImageContainer/>                <FieldContainer/>
         |                         |                                   |
         v                         v                                   v
```

[image: before]

What I want to do is expand a sidebar with a table when the button `Line Items` is clicked from the `FieldContainer`. This sidebar must be an overlay displayed over the `ImageContainer` at the same height(from top) as the trigger button `Line Items`.

[image: after]

I've tried using Accordion(React Bootstrap), Overlay(React Bootstrap), and Drawer(Material UI) none of them worked as expected. What component can I use.

Thanks in Advance!

Any help or tips will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that:

```
<FieldContainer>
  <LineItemsContainer>
    <ToggleButton>Line Items</ToggleButton>
    <CollapsibleTable />
  </LineItemsContainer>

  {/* Other elements */
</FieldContainer>
```

The styling will be

```
FieldContainer {
  overflow: visible;
}
LineItemsContainer {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

CollapsibleTable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 800px; // Dont need to set width for this element
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}
```

I don't have your code to test, but hope it can help you to resolve to issue.